# How do I fix a blurry screen problem?

Tags: 11.04, xorg, multiple-monitors

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop Samsung QX410. I also have Philips 221EL display. I want to use this display as the main one (instead of the laptop's one). But when I use it, the screen looks blurred. I thought that was a graphics driver-related problem, I spent much time trying to install the proper graphics driver. Finally I managed to do this (at least 3D effects work), but the display is still blurry. It is blurry while using any resolution - I tried a lot of them, including recommended 1920 x 1080 and refresh rate 60Hz. At the same time, laptop's display always looks OK. And the Philips monitor looks okay when using Windows, so it's an ubuntu-specific problem.

Comment: stupid answer, but: have you tried the "autoconfig" button on your monitor? (or something similar)

Comment: I did, but it didn't help... thanks anyway - I ended up using another monitor.

Comment: Were you using a vga cable? I've noticed blurry output with vga compared to dvi/hdmi

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)